# Trying to connect a PS 3 controller to OS X El Capitan

Tags: ps3, controllers, macos

I have a PS3 controller I want to connect to my MacBook. And when I open my Bluetooth settings, it shows I have successfully connected the controller.

However when I try to use any software that maps PS3 output to keyboard input (Enjoy2, Enjoyable, ControllerMate), none of the buttons seem to work.

I also tried Hyper Light Drifter, which is a game with in-built Controller support. Here the character walks to the upper left all the time, which seems to indicate that something reaches my computer from the controller.

Comment: I'm not terribly sure about how it works with a MacBook, but on Windows, I needed some extra drivers that basically fooled the system into thinking it was a 360 controller. The guides were only for Windows, but you may need to look into getting the drivers for OSX.